# Magento 2 :Custom payment - Stop sending order mail

Tags: magento2, custom, payment-methods, order-email

I have a custom payment module. I want to stop sending the default `Magento` order confirmation email for this payment method only.

Please give some solutions...

What I have done so far:

I have created one plugin

**`app/code/Company/OrderEmail/etc/di.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity">
        <plugin name="change_is_enable_method" type="Company\OrderEmail\Plugin\Sales\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentityPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**`app/code/Company/OrderEmail/Plugin/Sales/Order/Email/Container/OrderIdentityPlugin.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Company\OrderEmail\Plugin\Sales\Order\Email\Container;

class OrderIdentityPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @return bool
     */
    public function aroundIsEnabled(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/v1.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');

        $returnValue = $proceed();

        $paymentMethodCode = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod();

        $logger->info($paymentMethodCode);

        if($paymentMethodCode = "custom_paymentcode"){
            $forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess = $this->checkoutSession->getForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess();
            if(isset($forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess) && $forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess)
            {
                if($returnValue){
                    $returnValue = false;
                }
                else{
                    $returnValue = true;
                }     
                $this->checkoutSession->unsForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess();
            }

            return $returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not getting the `payment method` from the checkout session which I have logged into the `log` file. So I Am not not able to check the condition.

Answer (score 0):

### Extending the event Manager

Magento2 has event manager which fires when a specific event is getting fired.

If you want to code less Please also see [webhooks](https://marketplace.magento.com/mageplaza-module-webhook.html)

inside `Magento\vendor\temando\module-shipping-m2\etc\events.xml`

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="check_payment_method_to_Order" 
            instance="[Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Observer\ObserverforPaymentMethod" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer file:**

```
 <?php
    namespace [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

    class ObserverforPaymentMethodimplements ObserverInterface
    {

        public function __construct(
        ) {
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
         * @return void
         */
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            /***    Check your payment method here ***/
            //get order 
            $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderId);
            // get payment method
            $payment_method_code = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode(); 
            //Fetch the payment method code from order


        }
    }
```

**Other events to focus on**

checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Comment: After checking payment method, how can I send the mail.